# How to find declaration of a method in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij, and i cant find the declaration of a method. I could do this easily in eclipse wih a right-click -> go to method declaration.

Any hints please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ctrl+ Click for windows and cmd+ click on Mac, click on the function name(wherever it’s being used)

Answer (score -1):

To find a declaration, you can use `Command + B` on Mac or `Control + B` on Windows.

Steps to find the keymap that is being used in **Intellij** are the following:

**Step1** Open Settings/Preferences dialog by pressing `Command + ,`

**Step2:** Search for `KeyMap`. And click on it.

**Step3:** Search for the shortcut that you are looking for. For example, in your case, you want to search for a `declaration`.

You will find the keys that can be used for the action in the search result. Check the below image for more details.

[image: Shortcut keys Intellij]

You can also check here for more detail [IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html)